# Windows authentication in SilverLight Application (not Silverlight Business Application)

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, authentication

I am trying to add Windows authentication to an existing website that I have created. All information that I have read regarding using Windows authentication in silverlight requires that you start with the Silverlight Business Applicaion template instead of the Silverliight application template. I already have a website that I started writing using the Silverlight Application template. How can I add windows authentication to this existing website?

Answer (score 1):

If your application is hosted in IIS and this is a intranet site, you just need to set the application in IIS authentication method to Windows Authentication, then when the client tries to load the SL App a 401 challenge will trigger asking the user to enter in his/hers credentials. You can also set IE to pass with windows credentials to the server when the site is loaded.
I have had spent quite a bit of time tweaking various properties to get the right functionality that i am looking for (especially with machine names being fully qualifies or not) but basically that's one thing to keep in mind when debugging this is that machines names play a role in how the server interprets a client trying to access the server.